# Guava's LocalCache could not be used, why?

Tags: java, guava

Because this class is only package accessible.

Answer (score 4):

You're not meant to use that class directly. It's an implementation detail of the Guava cache package.

Build your cache using `CacheBuilder`.

There are a lot of classes that are package-private in Guava (and, of course, other libraries). They're simply not part of the public API.

Comment: Exactly the same way as with a method: omit the access modifier (e.g. public).

Comment: As I already stated: the lack of an access modifier means package-private.

Comment: Hah, I remember it! I must be on crack at that moment. The default access specifier is package. *-*